# WebP fallback images not loading

Tags: php, html, wordpress, webp, responsive-images

I'm using a `<picture>` tag to set a responsive image with WebP support.
I'm pulling a desktop image and mobile image URLs that have both `.web` and `.jpg` files.
for each media, I'm giving the `.webp` version and the `.jpg` version.

What I expect is that if the `.webp` version does not exist is that the website will take the .jpg file that exists.

any idea what is wrong here?

```
$image_desktop = get_field( 'desktop_image' ); // can be an .webp image or .jpg image
$image_mob     = get_field( 'mobile_image' ); // can be an .webp image or .jpg image
```

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 480px)"
  srcset="<?php echo esc_url( $image_desktop['url'] . '.webp' ); ?>"
  type="image/webp">

  <source srcset="<?php echo esc_url( $image_mob['url'] . '.webp' ); ?>" 
  type="image/webp">

  <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="<?php echo esc_url( $image_desktop['url'] ); ?>"
  type="image/jpeg">

  <source srcset="<?php echo esc_url( $image_mob['url'] ); ?>" type="image/jpeg">

  <img class="header-image"
  src="<?php echo esc_url( $image_desktop['url'] ); ?>"
  alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_desktop['url'] ); ?>">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

All URLs that you put in the `srcset` attributes have to be valid and have to exist.

Browsers that have support for WebP will try to load the URL from the `<source type="image/webp">` and all other browsers will try to load the URL from `<source type="image/jpeg">`. If the URL selected by the browser does not exist it will **not** fall back to one of the other `<source>`s.

You should check the existence of the image files on the server side.